# How can I fetch a channel ID?

Tags: discord.js

So I have some code that creates a temporary channel and I want it so when it opens it I can send an embed to the temp channel. This is the current script:

````
bot.on('message', msg =>{
      if(msg.content === (`${prefix}tempchannel`)) {
            var server = msg.guild;
            var name = msg.author.username;

            server.channels.create(`${name} temp channel.`, { reason: `Temp channel for ${name}` })

            msg.channel.send('Created a temp channel for you! Check your unreads.')

        }})```
 Could someone help me please?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GuildChannelManager.create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.3.1/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) returns a promise of the created channel.

```js
server.channels
  .create(`${name}-temp-channel`, { reason: `Temp channel for ${name}` })
  .then((channel) => channel.send("This is a new channel")); // channel callback
```